# Why is my array in my xaml data binding empty and saying its not an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

In my mixingPage xaml file I am trying to set the text content of a label to a value. I have a song which has an array of effects (abstract class) and an effect which has an array of effectItems. The problem occurs when i try to get data from the array in the effectItem. retrieving data from the effect array works fine. It does not matter which data I try to get from the effectItem array nor does it matter if the effect is abstract or not.

The mixingPage xaml code:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0"
Text="{Binding Effects[0].EffectItems.Length}"
VerticalOptions="Center"
Margin="10,0" />
```

The code navigating to this page:

```
Song song = new Song
{
    Effects = new List<Effect>
    {
        new Equalizer
        {
            EffectItems = new[]
            {
                new EffectItem { Name = "Low", Min = 1, Max = 0, Value = 5 }
            }
        }
    },
};

var mixingPage = new MixingPage();
mixingPage.BindingContext = song;
Navigation.PushAsync(mixingPage);
```

But it always gives the error:

```
0>MixingPage.xaml: Error  XamlC: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am using .NET Maui 6.0

I was expecting to write something along the lines of "{Binding Effects[0].EffectItems[0].Value}" and return the value stored in the effect item.

I tried removing the "abstract" from the class and using it as a alone standing class, I tried initializing the classes in the navigation in all different ways, changing the arrays to lists.
It always gives the error no matter what.

**Edit**
I forgot to specify that the Equalizer class you see in the song is a class extending the Effect abstract class.

Comment: are you **positive** its that chunk of XAML that is causing the problem?  This sounds like a compiler error caused by bad XAML, not a runtime binding error

Comment: Yes I'm sure because if i remove the binding or change the binding to something else it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I found a way around it. I changed the Effect class to just have a field with a "category" string instead of an effectItem which belongs to an effect.
Not the way I would have liked it to work, but I have been at it for about a week now with no results.

Comment: Hi @Yanergy, could you please accept your answer as accepted so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Label Grid.Column="0"
Text="{Binding Effects[0].EffectItems.Length}"
VerticalOptions="Center"
Margin="10,0" />
```

Based on the code you posted above, I found that the data structure of `Song` should be wrong.
It is not reasonable to create an object of class `Equalizer` inside the instantiated class `Song`.

If the structure of the class `Song.cs` is like this, there can be no error.

```
public class Song
{
    public List<Effect> Effects { get; set; }

}

public class Effect
{
    //public Equalizer equalizer { get; set; }

    public EffectItem[] EffectItems { get; set; }
}


public class EffectItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And we also need to change the data as follows while navigating to page `MixingPage`:

```
    private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Song song = new Song
        {  
             // adjust code like this 
            Effects = new List<Effect>
            {
                new Effect
               {
                EffectItems = new[]
               {
                 new EffectItem { Name = "Low", Min = 1, Max = 0, Value = 5 }
               }
            }

            },
        };

        var mixingPage = new MixingPage();
        mixingPage.BindingContext = song;
        Navigation.PushAsync(mixingPage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll have to give this a try, I think I remember trying it this way and it not working either. Also for more context, the Equalizer is a class extending from the abstract class Effect, so my thinking was that I could use it like I did.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, changing the Effect, but it still is not working like it is supposed to. I have tried most if not all possible combinations to try to get it to register but to no prevail. Calling length says it the property does not exist, trying to get something like EffectItem[0].Value says value is not set to an instance of an object...